# smartparens, how to copy unbalanced () code blocks?

Tags: smartparens

```
(defun ek/search-set-directory ()

....

)
```

Suppose I copy the first line which is not balanced,
then smartparen won't allow me to add `)`.
I can add it by using `C-q )`

Wonder if there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that’s exactly what `C-q` is designed for.

If you want a better way to insert defuns, then use yasnippet (or one of the many other similar packages) instead of copy and paste. This will let you avoid ever inserting unbalanced parens in the first place.